# Visual example of an infinite planar graph with degree sequence $(4^4,6^\infty)$

Tags: graph-theory, visualization, infinite-graphs

After reading some graph theory and talking with experts, I was intrigued. I would like to construct and visualise an infinite planar graph with degree sequence:
$$D=(4^4,6^\infty)$$ 
where the superscripts denote the number of vertices with that degree.

What is the number of graphs with this degree sequence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are infinitely many graphs with this degree sequence.

First, here is one possible graph with degree sequence $(6^\infty)$: an infinite triangular lattice.

[image: triangular lattice]

One way to add four vertices of degree $4$ is to pick two places where we "split up" a degree-$6$ vertex into two adjacent degree-$4$ vertices:

[image: modified triangular lattice]

There are other ways to make a graph with degree sequence $(4^4,6^\infty)$, but this operation can already be done in infinitely many non-isomorphic ways, since we can put the two pairs of degree-$4$ vertices arbitrarily far apart in the infinite lattice.

(And there are also other graphs we can start with that have degree sequence $(6^\infty)$, this one is just the nicest.)

Comment: The "rearrange the edges of a chunk of the lattice" plan is not quite that simple to execute without getting multiple edges. There are plenty of other possibilities, though.

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to construct an infinite **tree** with any reasonable sequence as its degree sequence. (All ones, for example, would not be reasonable.)

For starters, here is a tree whose degree sequence, in your notation, is $(5^1,6^\infty)$. The vertex set is the set of all finite sequences $\langle x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\rangle$ (including the null sequence) with $x_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, and with an edge joining $\langle x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\rangle$ to $\langle x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}\rangle$. The null sequence has degree $5$, the rest have degree $6$.

By imposing the further conditions $x_1\ne0$ and $x_1\in\{1,2,3\}\implies x_2\in\{1,2,3\}$ we get a tree with degree sequence $(4^4,6^\infty)$; the vertices of degree $4$ are the null sequence and the sequences $\langle1\rangle$, $\langle2\rangle$, and $\langle3\rangle$.

The number of **trees** with degree sequence $(4^4,6^\infty)$ is $\aleph_0$; each such tree is determined up to isomorphism by the smallest (finite) subtree containing all the vertices of degree $4$, those vertices being marked.

Comment: This is probably the best answer and I feel guilty for making things way too complicated.

Comment: Hmm, yes, and you can get all the way up to $2^{\aleph_0}$, say, by allowing the "tree" to have triangles in it here and there...

Answer (score 4):

If $6^\infty$ means that there are $\aleph_0$ vertices of degree $6$, then there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ isomorphism classes of such graphs.

There can't be *more* than that, because each graph with $\aleph_0$ vertices can be represented as a subset of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ in at least one way.

On the other hand, we can construct that many different graphs:

Start with an infinite tiling of the plane with equilateral triangles. That gives you an infinity of degree-6 vertices. Now pick two of them and split each of those two into two degree-4 vertices:

```
 \ /           \    /
--O--   -->   --O--O--
 / \           /    \
```

This gives at least one graph with your degree sequence. But there are uncountably many ways we can modify it to give rise to a non-isomorphic graph. Namely, somewhere in the grid we can slice it open with a cut stretching to infinity:

```
  \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ /
 --O---O---O---O---O---O---O---O--
  / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \
 O---O---O---O---O---O---O---O---O
  \ / \ / \ /
 --O---O---O---O---O---O---O---O--
  / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \
 O---O---O---O---O---O---O---O---O
  \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ /
```

and then fill the gap with another copy of the same sliced-open grid, stitched to your existing grid along the edge. (You'll need to squeeze it to make it fit, of course -- but even if your concept of "infinite planar graph" requires that the set of vertices has no limit points in the plane, you can achieve this by squeezing *most* of the the new copy out towards infinity such that at every finite distance from the place we're looking at here there's a certain minimal spacing between the vertices).

You can keep making such cuts and filling them in at different spacings. The *endpoints* of the original cuts will be topologically distinguishable from the rest of the graph, because they will be the only places in the graph there's a cycle of degree-6 vertices of length more than 3 where the shortest path between any two vertices in the cycle is along the cycle. We can encode an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb N$, for example, as the distances between those cut endpoints.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to include a discussion of cardinality or not. Thankfully, now we have one answer of each kind.

Answer (score 1):

In this graph I started with four vertices in the shape of a square, then kept connecting vertices in the interior to match the desired degree sequence.

[image]